# When opening documents from SP2013 in MS Office (via VPN), document not connected to server any more

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps, office-integration

I try to open a word/excel/office document from a SharePoint 2013 server.

Until last week that worked fine,
when opening a pptx file in Office Web Applications and then clicked on "Open in PowerPoint", the document opened in MS PowerPoint 2007 (local on my computer) and above the slides, I saw a new menu bar "server presentation" with a large button "check out".
I then could check the document in and thus create a new version on the SharePoint server.

Now (since some days) I don't see this "server presentation" menu bar anymore, the office document is saved locally on my computer and not connected to the SharePoint server and its original storage location anymore, so I can not check it out or check it in easily.

This is only the case on my computer, in others, it still works.

Any ideas/suggestions what is the problem?

EDIT

The problem **only seems to occur, when I log in to the network via VPN**.
When I connected directly to the company network via Ethernet, everything is ok.

Comment: Did you get an solution to this problem?

Comment: @brannmar: sorry, I don't remeber as it is very long ago and I could not find anything about that problem or its solution in my notes. :-(